# How to use find_library command to find multiple libs in Cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to link my target lib to batch of libs, which locate at one particular directory. But it seems that `find_library` command can match only one lib at a time.

Comment: Can you not call `find_library` multiple times?

Comment: There is too many libs...

Comment: So you don't want to list all libraries explicitly?

Comment: *"Too many libs"* That shouldn't be a reason to avoid calling `find_library` for every library separately. [`foreach()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/foreach.html) exists.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you can only match one library at a time. However, you can do multiple single-library matches and then put them together into a _LIBRARIES variable.
Here is an example snippet:

```
  find_library(MYMODULE_FIRST_LIBRARY NAMES MyLib1
      PATHS
      /usr/lib
      /usr/local/lib
      )
  find_library(MYMODULE_SECOND_LIBRARY NAMES MyLib2
      PATHS
      /usr/lib
      /usr/local/lib
      )
  if(MYMODULE_FIRST_LIBRARY AND MYMODULE_SECOND_LIBRARY)
    set(MYMODULE_LIBRARIES ${MYMODULE_FIRST_LIBRARY} ${MYMODULE_SECOND_LIBRARY})
    set(MYMODULE_FOUND TRUE)
    message(STATUS "Found MYMODULE: ${MYMODULE_LIBRARIES}")
    mark_as_advanced(MYMODULE_LIBRARIES MYMODULE_FIRST_LIBRARY MYMODULE_SECOND_LIBRARY)
```

The client code then adds ${MYMODULE_LIBRARIES} to the link line. Note that all of this is using the older style using Find. The more modern approach uses CONFIG and TARGETS rather than Find*.cmake files.

A good place to look for examples of this are the built-in Find*.cmake files installed along with CMake.